# Element moving slower when scrolling while using Butter Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make an element (element id #move-slower) move slower than the speed of the butter scroll container? My goal is to place this element somewhere behind the main container with the page content (which will use butter scroll) and have it move slower when scrolling than the container controlled by butter scroll.

I'm open to using other jQuery plugins other than butter scroll as long as  I can achieve the same effect of this plugin.

**Using:**
https://github.com/cmalven/butter-scroll

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer-container js-outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container js-inner-container">
  <div id="slower-element"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x300.png/09f/fff" alt=""></div>
   <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="col">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="col">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff" alt="">
     </div>
   </div>  
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
   new ButterScroll({
        $containerEl: jQuery('.js-outer-container'),
        $elToScroll: jQuery('.js-inner-container'),
        scrollEase: 0.07, // optional
        maxDepthOffset: 500 // optional
   });
```

**CSS**

```
.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.inner-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
#slower-element {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

**Fiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/ts7j3n5z/